# Almost infinite loop in Kotlin Minesweeper

Tags: kotlin, for-loop

I'm working on **minesweeper** project at JetBrainsAcademy. I got the error `In this test, the program is running for a long time, more than 15 seconds. Most likely, the program has gone into an infinite loop.` I suppose, that the functions `setMines()` has almost infinitive loop, but I can't handle this problem. Could you show me the better solution for setting mines?

```
package minesweeper

import kotlin.random.Random

const val SIZE = 9

fun main() {
    println("How many mines do you want on the field?")
    val numberOfMines = readln().toInt()

    println(Board(SIZE))

    println("Set/unset mine marks or claim a cell as free:")
    val (x, y, _) = readln().split(" ")
    val board = Board(SIZE, numberOfMines, mapOf("x" to x.toInt() - 1, "y" to y.toInt() - 1))

    while (board.isNotWon()) {
        println("Set/unset mine marks or claim a cell as free:")
        val (x, y, action) = readln().split(" ")

        val notMine = Pair(x.toInt() - 1, y.toInt() - 1)

        when (action) {
            "free" -> {
                if (board.checkCell(notMine.first, notMine.second)) board.endGame()
                else board.explore(notMine.first, notMine.second)
            }
            "mine" -> {
                board.toggleMarking(notMine.first, notMine.second)
            }
        }
        println(board)
    }
    println(board)
    println("Congratulations! You found all the mines!")
}

data class Cell(private val x: Int, private val y: Int, var isMine: Boolean = false) {
    private var number = 0
    var isMarked = false
    var isExplored = false

    fun add() = number++

    fun notHasMinesAround(): Boolean = number > 0

    fun makeMine() {
        isMine = true
    }

    fun toggleMark() {
        isMarked = !isMarked
    }

    fun explore() {
        isExplored = true
        isMarked = false
    }

    fun showMine() {
        if (isMine) explore()
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return if (isMarked) "*" else if (!isExplored) "." else if (isMine) "X" else if (number == 0) "/" else number.toString()
    }

    fun isNotMine(): Boolean = !isMine

}

data class Board(
    override val size: Int, val numberOfMines: Int = 0, val notMine: Map<String, Int> = emptyMap()
) : MutableList<MutableList<Cell>> by mutableListOf(mutableListOf()) {

    private val mines = mutableSetOf<Cell>()
    private val markedCells = mines
    private val unExploredCells = mines

    init {
        this.clear()
        for (x in indices) {
            val line = mutableListOf<Cell>()
            for (y in indices) {
                line.add(Cell(x, y))
                unExploredCells.add(line[y])
            }
            this.add(line)
        }
        setMines()
        if (notMine.isNotEmpty()) this[notMine["x"]!!][notMine["y"]!!].explore()

    }


    private fun setMines() {
        var minesToSet = numberOfMines

        while (minesToSet != 0) {
            val x = Random.nextInt(0, SIZE - 1)
            val y = Random.nextInt(0, SIZE - 1)

            val cell = this[x][y]
            if (!cell.isMine && x != notMine["x"] && y != notMine["y"]) {
                cell.makeMine()
                minesToSet--
                mines.add(cell)
                for (row in arrayOf(x - 1, x, x + 1)) {
                    if (row in indices) for (column in arrayOf(
                        y - 1, y, y + 1
                    )) if (column in indices) this[row][column].add()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun checkCell(x: Int, y: Int): Boolean = this[x][y].isMine

    fun toggleMarking(x: Int, y: Int) {
        val y = y - 1
        val cell = this[x][y]
        cell.toggleMark()
        if (cell.isMarked) markedCells.add(cell)
        else markedCells.remove(cell)

    }


    fun endGame() {
        this.forEach { it -> it.forEach { it.showMine() } }
        println("You stepped on a mine and failed!")
    }

    fun explore(x: Int, y: Int) {
        val cell = this[x][y]
        if (!cell.isExplored) {
            cell.explore()
            unExploredCells.remove(cell)

            for (row in arrayOf(x - 1, x, x + 1)) {
                if (row in this.indices)
                    for (column in arrayOf(y - 1, y, y + 1)) {
                    if (column in this.indices && cell.isNotMine() && cell.notHasMinesAround())
                        this[row][column].explore()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun isNotWon(): Boolean = !(markedCells == mines || unExploredCells == mines)

    override fun toString(): String {
        var output = " │123456789│\n—│—————————│\n"
        for (i in indices) output += this[i].joinToString(separator = "", prefix = "${i + 1}│", postfix = "|\n")

        output += "—│—————————│"
        return output

    }
}
```

Comment: If `minesToSet` happens to be negative, then the loop would run for a long time (until it overflows and then eventually reaches 0). I would change the while-loop condition to `minesToSet > 0` to stop that earlier.

Comment: But I would guess that your real problem is `if (!cell.isMine && x != notMine["x"] && y != notMine["y"])` never giving true, which causes `minesToSet` to never decrement.

Comment: Ok, thanks @marstran. Now I see, that I wass looking for the cause in the wrong part of my code. Thanks <3

Comment: I've change my condition to `if (x != cannotBeMine["x"] || y != cannotBeMine["y"]) {
                val cell = this[x][y]
                if (!cell.isMine) {` and I got the error again... (notMine -> cannotBeMine)

Comment: I spotted another mistake. `Random.nextInt(0, SIZE - 1)` needs to be `Random.nextInt(0, SIZE)` because the second argument needs to be one higher than the highest value you want

Comment: Also `if (!cell.isMine && x != notMine["x"] && y != notMine["y"]) {` needs to be `if (!cell.isMine && !(x == notMine["x"] && y == notMine["y"])) {` because otherwise mines can't be placed anywhere in the same column or row of the chosen spot

Comment: You are also only calling `add()` with mines that are not along the edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Conditions from `if (!cell.isMine && x != notMine["x"] && y != notMine["y"])` to `if (!cell.isMine && !(x == cannotBeMine["x"] && y == cannotBeMine["y"]))`
2. Generating mines from `Random.nextInt(0, SIZE - 1)` to `Random.nextInt(0, SIZE)`
   Thanks @marstran and @Ivo Beckers